# Lambda in a child account needs to get contact information unisng role in an administrative account

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

Today I have a very specific problem.

I have four accounts in my organization:
Account_000 - normal account
Account_001 - normal account child
Account_002 - Administrative Account
Account_003 - Root account

I have set set up a cross account Role in Account_002 (administrative) with following permissions:

```
            "organizations:ListAccounts",
            "organizations:ListAccountsForParent",
            "organizations:ListParents",
            "organizations:ListChildren",
            "organizations:ListRoots",
            "organizations:ListTagsForResource",
            "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit",
            "account:GetContactInformation">
```

The Account_001 has a lambda function that uses the cross account role from Account_002 to pull data about all accounts (except root account) into the organization. It pulls following information: tags, account ID, join type, join time, account ARN number and Contact Information

When I execute function on Account_001 lambda gets error not authorized to get contact information.

I can get contact information from each of the accounts in organization using CLI from the root account.

I am unable to get contact information from any of the accounts using any other account than root.

How do I make sure that the Administrative account can access contact information about other accounts?

How do I make sure that the lambda function in Account_001 can access contact information from other accounts?

This will hopefully help to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/accounts/latest/reference/API_GetContactInformation.html) :  "the caller must be an identity in the organization's management account or a delegated administrator account. The specified account ID must also be a member account in the same organization. The organization must have all features enabled, and the organization must have trusted access enabled for the Account Management service, and optionally a delegated admin account assigned." Does your scenario meet _all_ of those requirements?

Comment: The account is a delegated administrator account and it is part of the organization.
The organization seems to have a trusted access because I am able to pull information about accounts (i.e. OU in which account is located or account name), but I am unable to pull ContactInformation. 
 
I am not sure what are "all features enable" means. I will need to go over this part 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_org_support-all-features.html

Comment: Can you please advise a method to check if all features are enabled and if the trusted access is enabled?